# Anyone tried submitting hs_err files to Sun?

Tags: sun, bug-reporting, jvm-crash

I run a lot of java code on my servers, and occasionally I get a JVM crash, accompanied by a crash dump `hs_err_pid` file.

Lately I've decided to try to be a better netizen, so I examined the latest crash log, made sure it was indeed the latest JVM, and that the crash was not caused by an external library, and then I tried submitting the file to [Sun's bug database](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp).

However, it seems that the entire submitting process is geared towards **preventing** you from submitting bug reports, making sure you check the box to verify you understand that THIS IS NOT A PLACE TO RECEIVE SUPPORT, and forcing you to fill all this information that they could actually get from the crash file, and some more completely irrelevant information like my company name and Sun account ID.

So my question is twofold:

1. Is there some backdoor through which I can just say, "look, here's a crash log, do what you like with it"?
2. Should I even bother? It seems that Sun is hinting that they have enough bug reports as it is, and they don't really need people sending them more crash log files.

What should I do?

**EDIT**: In case I wasn't clear enough, I'm just trying to help Sun and the community. I don't expect any fixes, explanations or support.

On the other hand, I don't care enough about these crashes to put any effort into reproducing them or investigating them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do, but only with the understanding (hope?) that this is only for the greater good.  I have never received a response or follow up.

> However, it seems that the entire
>   submitting process is geared towards
>   preventing you from submitting bug
>   reports, making sure you check the box
>   to verify you understand that THIS IS
>   NOT A PLACE TO RECEIVE SUPPORT, and
>   forcing you to fill all this
>   information that they could actually
>   get from the crash file, and some more
>   completely irrelevant information like
>   my company name and Sun account ID.

My read is that it is geared toward *'setting expectations'*.   I'm sure there are, despite the process you complain about, zillions of folks who submit a report and then expect a person email from James Gosling himself in under two hours with a patch or workaround.

The contact info stuff is probably for a hypothetical Sun engineer that actually wants to contact you about the report with other questions.

Don't forget that Sun has a paid support programs, and that this crash report system is not where Sun customers are supposed to get support.

So, to directly answer your questions:

1. Use the front door.  Why wouldn't you?
2. Yes, you should bother.  Just don't expect any feedback.